# What are the diff between using '{'...'}' and '%'...'%' as a quote for PHP preg_ function?

Tags: php, regex

What are the different between this two diff statement? Any reference document?

```
'{<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">.*?</table>}si' -> Success
'%<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">.*?</table>%si' -> Fail
```

Comment: What do you mean with "any reference document"? Something like the [introduction to PCRE](http://es.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you are using a delimiter that's used inside of your string, (`100%`), if you decided to use % as a delimiter, you need to escape any instance of % inside the string with a backslash. The following will work:

```
'%<table width="100\%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">.*?</table>%si'
```

Comment: Ah, I overlooked that one. And misunderstood where the confusion stems from.

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric, non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (/), hash signs (#) and tildes (~). The following are all examples of valid delimited patterns.
>
> ```
> /foo bar/
> #^[^0-9]$#
> +php+
> %[a-zA-Z0-9_-]%
> ```
>
> In addition to the aforementioned delimiters, it is also possible to use bracket style delimiters where the opening and closing brackets are the starting and ending delimiter, respectively.
>
> ```
> {this is a pattern}
> ```

So they're both equivalent, it's just that one uses a delimiter of the first style and the other uses braces. But both are delimiting the regex. Regex options come after the closing delimiter in both cases.